# Run commands when cpu is hot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, cooling, development

A pleasure to introduce myself, I am a user of Ubuntu and I have the following problem: I have a notebook whose cooling system is VERY bad, when it reaches 90 ° C it turns off, it never goes down. The momentary solution I found was to limit the cpu clock, lowering it from 2.1ghz to 1.3ghz. at that speed even if stressed an hour It does not turn off.
I know that the ideal would be to acquire a new refrigeration system but it is impossible for me at this time, so it occurred to me to do the following When the CPU reaches 85 ° C, underclock from 2.1 to 1.3, and when the temperature drops to 80 ° C, remove the underclock.

The commands I use for the underlock are as follows

"echo 1300000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_freq" and "echo 1300000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_freq"

At some point I have dedicated myself to programming, but to carry out this task of a "service" that monitors the temperature and Take some action when it reaches a certain value that escapes me, since I have only programmed mathematical simulations.

What do you recommend that I do? Considering that I know absolutely nothing about using dependencies etc ... How should I start?

Greetings and thanks

Edit 1: I'm running xubuntu with xfce and Lxde

Comment: [`cpufreqd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/cpufreqd.8.html)

Comment: You shouldn't need a new cooling system, just new thermal paste on the processor. Not that it helps a whole lot as you likely don't have any on hand and will need to know how to apply it on top of that. On the bright side it's pretty cheap at about $10USD or less, so much more reasonable than a new processor or more powerful cooling system.

Comment: I have changed the thermal paste a lot of times, but it has not solved it (could it be that maybe my thermal paste is old / not so effective?)